# kotlin and android: is it necessary to cancel previously setup callbacks?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, callback, kotlin

Kotlin+android rookie, so please be nice :)

In my app, the menu options come from a database which is  refreshed from time to time. I'm using an AsyncTask to get the required items and since I'm using Switches to select/deselect the items, I'm handling the checked "event" to handle the selections:

```
switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener({ buttonView, isChecked -> ... })
```

As I said,  I end up replacing the menu items with new ones. Should I pass null the switchs' setOnCheckedChangeListener methods before replacing the menu items to avoid a memory leak or am I safe?

thanks.

Luis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you dont have to pass null as previous anonymous classes will be replaced by new ones and previous ones would be collected by garbage collector automatically. Any object that has 0 references is automatically released